# Stop Vista creating GBs of error report files

Tags: windows-vista, hard-drive, cleaning

I was using the Disk Cleanup for Vista and I noticed that I have over 20GB of queued or archived Windows Error Report files. I only have an 80GB boot drive so I really need that space. Since they are listed in Disk Cleanup I assume that they are safe to delete.

My question is how do I stop Vista creating them in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Control Panel open System Maintenance

Open Problem Reports and Solutions.

In the left pane, click Change settings.

Click Advanced Settings.

Under "For my programs, problem reporting is:"
Click Off

Click OK.  If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

From Problem Reports and Solutions

Click Clear solution and problem history

Note: Doing this means Microsoft (and hence the software manufacturer they pass the info to) will no longer receive notice of problems occurring on your computer. So you won't receive fixes for those problems either.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but that's a superb answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Go here:

Control Panel > System and Maintenance > Problem Reports and Solutions > Change settings > Advanced settings

there you can turn it off altogether or only for certain program.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 this is available under the Action Centre - Maintenance.